# Is it possible for me to call a list with a string interger having the same text of a list

Tags: python, string, list, str-replace, execute

```
l1 = [...]
l2 = [...]
l3 = [...]
l4 = [...]
.
.
.
ln = [...] #n is a interchangeable number

...

x = input() # I will control this input so x is int and range 1 to n
x = str(x)
a = str("l" + x)
```

There are n list in this program
they are named from l1 to ln (n is a possitive interger)
The user will then enter a number x between 1 to 100
transvert x into string
a = str ("l" + x) #lx in str
**Is it possible to execute lx with a**
I know a.append for example doesn't work because it says," 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: strongly suggest using a dictionary for this.

Comment: What's a string integer?

Comment: A 2d list will work: `l = [[...],[...],...,[...]]; print(l[x])`